# Convert emission inventory (.csv) to (.nc4) - 2D Variable Issue

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv, netcdf

Thank you in advance for assistance with this issue. I have been working tirelessly to get this working, but as a non-expert I've found myself stuck with the following issue.

**Goal:** I would like to convert a gridded emission inventory in .csv format to netCDF (.nc4). I am able to do so with the framework below, but I am unable to specify that 'Out_tonnes_per_year_by_cell' is a plottable 2D variable referencing lat and lon.

Here is all of the information I believe you'll need:

**Metadata for .csv file:**

```
s1
Out[2]: 
        Long   Lat  Out_tonnes_per_year_by_cell
0     -179.5 -89.5                          0.0
1     -178.5 -89.5                          0.0
2     -177.5 -89.5                          0.0
3     -176.5 -89.5                          0.0
4     -175.5 -89.5                          0.0
     ...   ...                          ...
64795  175.5  89.5                          0.0
64796  176.5  89.5                          0.0
64797  177.5  89.5                          0.0
64798  178.5  89.5                          0.0
64799  179.5  89.5                          0.0

[64800 rows x 3 columns]
```

**Body of Python Script:**

```
# Fetches internal data of target .csv (Excel) or .xlsx (Excel) files and writes to .nc (NetCDF)
# By doing so, this will allow for the import of key climate variable data directly into HEMCO within GEOS-Chem GCHP


# Key Module Import(s)
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

# Key Variable(s)
kw = dict(sep = '\s*', parse_dates = {'dates':[0,1]}, header = None, index_col = 0, squeeze = True, engine = 'python')
GEO_C2H6_Dir = ('E:/PSU/CCAR REU/Emission(s) Inventories (GEOS-CHEM)/Simulation Data/Geo-CH4_emission_grid_files (Geologic)/Gridded Geologic C2H6 - Emissions Inventory/') # Geologic C2H6 Data Directory

# Load csv file into Python
GEO = (GEO_C2H6_Dir + 'Total_geoC2H6_output_2018.csv') # Location of Global Geologic C2H6 Emission Data

# Read into Pandas Series
s1 = pd.read_csv(GEO, sep = ",", skipinitialspace = True)

# Name of Each Pandas Series
s1.name = 'GEOCH4_Total'

# Concatenate Pandas Series into an Aggregated Pandas DataFrame
df1 = pd.concat([s1], axis = 1)

# Create Xarray Dataset from Pandas DataFrame
xds1 = xr.Dataset(df1)

# Addition of Variable Attribute Metadata
xds1['Long'].attrs = {'units':'1', 'Long_Name':'Longitudinal coordinate in decimal degrees'}
xds1['Lat'].attrs = {'units':'1', 'Long_Name':'Latitudinal coordinate in decimal degrees'}
xds1['Out_tonnes_per_year_by_cell'].attrs = {'units':'1', 'Long_Name':'Total Output of Cumulative Methane in units of Tonnes per Year in each Cell'}

# Addition of Global Attribute Metadata
xds1.attrs = {'Conventions':'CF-1.0', 'Title':'Total_GEOCH4_Output_2018', 'summary':'Total output of Cumulative Geologic Emitted Methane from 2018'}

# Save to Output NetCDF
xds1.to_netcdf('E:/PSU/CCAR REU/Emission(s) Inventories (GEOS-CHEM)/Simulation Data/Geo-CH4_emission_grid_files (Geologic)/Gridded Geologic C2H6 - Emissions Inventory/Total_GEOCH4_Output_2018.nc')
```

Output:

1.
[Variable type comparison between output file and example emission inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FJEh.png)

2.
[2D variable information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6EM8.png)

3.
['Out_tonnes_per_year_by_cell' variable information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAjSc.png)

My hunch is that it has to do with the different format(s). At this point, I am unsure what I can do to correct for this. **ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Once again, thanks in advance and kind regards!**

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve this by replacing your lines setting up the xarray dataset, as follows:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(["Lat", "Long"])
xds1 = xr.Dataset(df1)
```

This will ensure that Lat/Long are the coordinates/dimensions of the xarray dataset, and this should guarantee you have a valid netCDF file in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I regrettably got this error after implementing your substitute. Any ideas?

"NotImplementedError: variable 'dim_0' is a MultiIndex, which cannot yet be serialized to netCDF files (https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1077). Use reset_index() to convert MultiIndex levels into coordinate variables instead."

Comment: And with : `xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df1.set_index(["Lat", "Long"]))`, do you get the same error ?